# how to switch back to parent node from child node using xpath

Tags: xpath

I need to know the Xpath of the following html code: here what i want is detect 4x6 text first comeback to input select the radio button

```
<div class="span-5 prepend-01 prepend-top last format">
     <h5 style="color:#41393b;font-weight:bold">Select your Size</h5>
     <div class="size-info">
            <input type="radio" value="http://www.staging.photojaanic.com/productdesign/5/10104" checked="checked" name="selection"/>
               4x6   
            <span class="right">Rs.3.45*</span>
            <br/>
```

I wrote the following xpath`//div[contains(text(),'4x6')]` but it doesn't select the text it just selects the full `input` can anyone suggest me how to achieve it.

Comment: what do you want the XPath to return, is it the `input` tag? `//text()[contains(.,'4x6')]/preceding-sibling::input[1]`

Answer (score 0):

> "how to switch back to parent node from child node using xpath?"

Use `parent::*` (or using shortcut for the same: `..`) or `ancestor::*`, depending on what you *actually* mean by parent. But I have failed to see how this title relates to the description in the body of your question. Another thing is, `//div[contains(text(),'4x6')]` only checks the first text node in the current `div`. To checks for all text nodes, use the following instead : `//div[text()[contains(.,'4x6')]]`

> "here what i want is detect 4x6 text first comeback to input select the radio button"

It is still hard to understand what you mean *exactly* by that sentence, but if you meant to select `input` element that come before the text `"4x6"`, then you can try something like this :

```
//text()[contains(.,'4x6')]/preceding-sibling::input[1]
```